# Regular Expression for URL with parameters

Tags: php, regex

I am using below expression to valid URL like this:
http://www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe

```
(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.linkedin)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))
```

But the validation only works for http://www.linkedin.com

If I enter the full url with parameters, It's not working. Please help.

Comment: I would say it does not work for `http://www.linkedin.com` either. The `$` in the pattern followed by the port specification can be translated into "match end of string followed by colon and some digits". But it would be quite difficult to find chars after the string has ended... :-P Use `parse_url` or `filter_var` as suggested by @Denis below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you have will fail because it checks for a string end after the TLD (see `$` after `se)`). Also, it will only validate "linked.in" URLs.

So, you must let more characters. Here is your [fixed regex](https://regex101.com/r/vP9bT6/1).

```
^(?>(?:https?|ftp):\/\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.linkedin\.(?:com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se))(?:(?:\/[^\/\r\n]*)*)?)$
```

It matches both:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe
http://www.linkedin.com
```

A [sample program](http://goo.gl/XXghLP):

```
<?php
   $re = "/^(?>(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\\.linkedin\\.(?:com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se))(?:(?:\\/[^\\/\\r\\n]*)*)?)$/m"; 
   $str = "http://www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe\n\nhttp://www.linkedin.com"; 
   preg_replace_callback($re, function ($matches) {
        echo "Matched: " . $matches[0] . "\n";
      },  $str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this regex:

```
(?i)(?:https?|ftps?)://[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*\.linkedin+\.(?:com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co\.uk|biz|se)(?::\d+)?(?:/.*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

There error in your expression, you clearly identified linkedin.

Use this:

```
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp

Comment: Thank you for help. Is there a way to edit the expression itself to do this?